# vs code container is not displaying version control

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I started development in container via vs code remote development
Now i get to the source controll of the vs code gui and press publish to github
It works I see files on the github.com but when i change some file I do not see possibility of commiting it just as if the repository would be not created.

image **after** succesfully created github repository

[image]